# Unable to move element to bottom of page in css

Tags: html, css

I can't move an element down. The text should go down when I add `bottom:0;` but it does not work.

```css
.ft {
  /*This is the ft image*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 80.2%;
  top: 84.3%;
}

.copyright {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  left: 33%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="copyright">
  © Statecraft.ch &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ip Statecraft.ch<br> All rights
  reserved &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; info@statecraft.ch
</div>

<div class="ft">
  <img src="https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/3e9a63c44d5a3a20f8cb60e87bc7c36a/258c51bd/Ft-img.png">
</div>
```

Comment: It is probably because you have no other content on your page. Add some spam content, some divs with text in it ...etc.

Comment: Give  `position: absolute;` to `.copyright`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the CSS block that makes the respective changes.

```
.ft {
 /*This is the ft image*/
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 left: 80.2%;
 top: 84.3%;
}

.ft img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 margin: auto;
}

.copyright {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 0;
 left: 33%;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

Position for the `div ft` should be provided *relative* and position for `div copyright` should be provided *absolute*. Along with image size in `division ft` to be provided accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ft {
  /*This is the ft image*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 80.2%;
  top: 84.3%;
}

.copyright {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  left: 33%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="copyright">
  © Statecraft.ch &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ip Statecraft.ch<br> All rights
  reserved &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; info@statecraft.ch
</div>

<div class="ft">
  <img src="https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/3e9a63c44d5a3a20f8cb60e87bc7c36a/258c51bd/Ft-img.png">
</div>
```

Position should be absolute not relative